# How to read an image into a file?

Tags: php

I want my PHP script to **load an image from a file system** and pass it through an AJAX response to javascript which then loads the image into the browser using FileReader. I can't use image src for this because the  file system is private and can't be accessed directly.

The only solution I have found is to use functions imagecreatefromjpg, imagecreatefrompng, etc. The problem with these functions is that they consume a lot more memory that the actual image size is. All I want is to pass the image as an ordinary file and let the javascript handle it.

EDIT:

I have some images stored in */private/images*. Private folder blocks access through .htaccess. I basically send an AJAX request from */public/test.php* to a handler, */public/handler.php*, which should access */private/images* and send back an image specified by a filename and an extension.

So far, I am testing with only a few images, so I just hardcode the name into the function call.

Comment: Should be much easier if you show how your PHP page knows what file to load.

Comment: I am completely lost. I know how to get an image from a HTML form and save it but I have no clue how to get it back without specifying src.

Comment: Use `<img src="getimage.php?image=name.gif"` then the PHP file just does `readfile('/private/images/'.$_GET['image']);`.  That is an insecure example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readfile` and send appropriate headers for your file:

```
$fileMimeType = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $filePath);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
header("Content-Type: " . $fileMimeType);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: public");
readfile($filePath);
```